# Does anyone known a source where find from which characters the modern one borrowed their loaned meanings?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin, loanwords

Like I said in the title I would really like to know if anyone knows where to find the original characters that gave to the modern one their loaned meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually we use 《辞海》 to look up all the meanings of a character. I'm not sure if you have it at hand. However I searched the online resources and found a website could meet your requirement, http://www.zdic.net

Good luck!